# given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#

I inherited a project that gives users the above error while trying to retrieve lost password in a .Net 4.0 project. I stepped through and found the trouble spot, but the problem is, the values generated seem right so I don't why the error is occurring. Thanks in advance to anyone who can look at the following code and help me find out how to fix it. Let me know if more information is needed. I looked through everything I could find but nothing gave me clues I could use. Problem is that I just can't trace where the key/value combination should enter, nor would I know how to add it once I did. Code follows.

I posted a similar discussion at http://forums.asp.net/t/1926444.aspx/1?given+key+was+not+present+in+the+dictionary but no one there knew how to help me.

```
void EmailUser(User user)
{
    user.ChangePasswordID = Guid.NewGuid();
    user.Save();
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
    //problem line below
    email.From = new MailAddress(Settings.LostPasswordEmailFrom);
    email.To.Add(new MailAddress(uxEmail.Text));
    email.Subject = Settings.LostPasswordSubject;
    email.Body = EmailTemplateService.HtmlMessageBody(EmailTemplates.MembershipPasswordRecovery, new { Body = Settings.LostPasswordText, BeginRequired = "", EndRequired = "", UserName = user.Name, GUID = user.ChangePasswordID.ToString() });
    email.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Send(email);

    uxSuccessPH.Visible = true;
    uxQuestionPanel.Visible = false;
    uxUserInfoPanel.Visible = false;
    uxUserNameLabelSuccess.Text = uxEmail.Text;
}

/// <summary>
/// The address that the lost password email will be sent from
/// </summary>
public static string LostPasswordEmailFrom
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SiteSettings.GetSettingKeyValuePair()["LA_MembershipProvider_lostPasswordEmailFrom"]))
            return Globals.Settings.FromEmail;
        return SiteSettings.GetSettingKeyValuePair()["LA_MembershipProvider_lostPasswordEmailFrom"];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code of `SiteSettings` class as well?

Comment: -3 on a question of a new user, really? If you have the urge to downvote a question, maybe you could explain what he could do to improve it, come back to see if he improved it and turn it into a +1 as an encouragement. This is how communities are build.

Comment: Achakravarty, how do I share that code? This comment box has a limitation on the number of characters, which is much less than the code I need to enter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

when you call  `SiteSettings.GetSettingKeyValuePair()["LA_MembershipProvider_lostPasswordEmailFrom"])` if there is no key named `LA_MembershipProvider_lostPasswordEmailFrom` you will get *"The given key was not present in the dictionary"* error. What you can do is, check the whether key exist first and then get the value. You can do as below

```
public static string LostPasswordEmailFrom
{
    get
    { 
        var kvp = SiteSettings.GetSettingKeyValuePair();

        if (kvp == null || !kvp.ContainsKey("LA_MembershipProvider_lostPasswordEmailFrom"))
            return Globals.Settings.FromEmail;
        return kvp["LA_MembershipProvider_lostPasswordEmailFrom"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Damith, the code above seems to have done it. Can you explain the difference? How do I give it a favorable vote?

Comment: @muybn Glad that my answer helped you. updated with details as you request.